# futures, promises, and exceptions

Tags: c++, asynchronous, c++11

```
std::promise<int> p1;
auto f = p1.get_future();

{
    std::promise<int> p2(std::move(pr));
}

bool valid = f.valid(); // true
f.wait(); // does not throw, or fail, but returns immediately
f.get(); // throws an exception
```

Is there any way to check if a future is going to throw before calling `get`? I hoped `valid` would check... I'm not really sure how to get `valid` to return false. Destroying the `promise` without setting a value doesn't do it.

Comment: A `std::future` can be seen as an observer to the state of a `std::promise`. If the promise is gone, the future is dangling. It's not UB as sehe says, but you get a `std::broken_promise` exception, because the promise can never be fullfilled.

Comment: valid will return false once you called `get` or `share` once.

Comment: [future::valid](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future/valid) says `Checks if the future refers to a shared state`. If the promise is gone and the value was never set shouldn't that mean there is no shared state?

Comment: @Dave, _"If the promise is gone and the value was never set"_ Read the effects of the `promise` destructor, it makes the state ready. _"shouldn't that mean there is no shared state?"_ No, the `future` still refers to the state (it's not "shared" with anything else, but still exists) so you can retrieve the result, which in this case is a `future_error` exception with error code `broken_promise`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there any way to check if a future is going to throw before calling
>   get?

No, as that would be somehow equal to receive the value stored in the future.

> I hoped valid would check... I'm not really sure how to get valid to
>   return false.

Valid will return true if the future refers to a shared state which can only be created by `std::async`, `std::packaged_task` or `std::promise`. A counterexample would be a default constructed `std::future`. Valid will also be false once you have called `get` or `share` on a valid(valid == true) future once.
Calling any other function than `valid` or the move-assignment operator on an invalid(valid == false) future is UB.

> Destroying the promise without setting a value doesn't do it.

No, that as mentioned above is not the point of valid, as the future still refers to shared state just that the other side - the promise - wasn't fulfilled. If on destruction of a promise no value or exception was set, an exception to indicate the broken promise is set.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way to check if a future is going to throw before calling get?

Your question is equivalent to:
Is there any way to check if a *function* is going to throw before calling it?

The answer to both questions is, in general, no.

Consider:

```
int func_that_might_throw()
{
  if (rand() % 2)
    throw 1;
  return 0;
}

std::future<int> f = std::async(&func_that_might_throw);

int result = f.get();
```

The `async` call could return a deferred function, in which case the function doesn't even run until you call `get()`, so in general there is no way to tell in advance whether the result will be a value or an exception.  (You can detect a deferred function by calling `f.wait_for(std::chrono::seconds(0))`, but `async` might not return a deferred function, and in that case the function could still be running asynchronously when you try to check if it has a stored exception, so you'd have to check if it's ready and has a stored exception, so checking just gets very messy.)

A valid `future` with a shared state that is ready has a result, which is either a value or an exception. Both are valid results.  If you don't want to handle exceptions then you should ensure an exception is not set in the shared state in the first place.

Comment: In future::get doesn't there have to be something like `if(IsReady()) return value; else if(!PromiseExists()) throw broken:promise;`? Therefore there could be a function that returns `!IsReady() && !PromiseExists()`. I don't really understand why this case isn't suited to be invalid (... `valid() == false`) but the designers didn't do that.

Comment: To briefly speak of my use case: I kick off a bunch of async tasks (using my own async queue, not std::async) every frame (~20). The next frame I want to cancel any tasks which didn't execute yet and push a new group of 20 to be potentially executed. I want my async queue to return me a future when I push a job into it, but if I can't tell that a job has been canceled or not by using the future I can't use futures, or I'll have to wrap them. I can do it by calling get and catching the exception, but that's too slow.

Comment: To your first comment: The `broken_promise` gets set when the promise goes away, not when you look for the result. `valid()` means "has shared state" and the future still has a shared state, as has been stated several times now.

Comment: Second comment: you could use a `future<boost::optional<result>>` and set an empty `optional<result>` as the result when the task got cancelled, instead of just letting the `promise` go out of scope without making the state ready

Comment: To expand on what `valid()` means: it's **undefined behaviour** to call `get()` if the future has no shared state, so `valid()` exists to tell you whether calling `get()` or `wait()` or `wait_for()` is safe. It does not exist to tell you what sort of result (value or exception) is stored, however much you might want that.

Comment: Thanks. I realized that the first future that throws means the rest will too if I am calling `get()` sequentially. So, it's okay performance-wise.